# Как соединить dataframes pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У нас есть два `dataframe`:

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['a','b']})
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name2': ['a1','a2', 'b1', 'b2']})
```

Нужно получить третий `dataframe` в следующем виде:

```
test3 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['a','a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'Name2': ['a1','a2', 'b1', 'b2','a1','a2', 'b1', 'b2']})
```

То есть, для каждой строки из первой таблицы соответствуют все строки из второй.

Думал, что можно использовать `merge`, `concat` и т.д., но что-то не выходит.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте `merge()` c параметром `how='cross'` - [создает декартово произведение из обоих фреймов, сохраняет порядок левых ключей](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html#:%7E:text=cross%3A%20creates%20the%20cartesian%20product%20from%20both%20frames%2C%20preserves%20the%20order%20of%20the%20left%20keys.).

```
test1 = pd.DataFrame({'Name1': ['a','b']})
test2 = pd.DataFrame({'Name2': ['a1','a2', 'b1', 'b2']})
df = test1.merge(test2,how='cross')
print(df)
```

```
  Name1 Name2
0     a    a1
1     a    a2
2     a    b1
3     a    b2
4     b    a1
5     b    a2
6     b    b1
7     b    b2
```